# KSH/bash for File Creation Dynamically

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have a directory name tmp on that directory on basis of FileName Category I wanted to create 'n' number of files dynamically.

```
   if [ ! -d tmp ]
then
    mkdir tmp
fi

TEMPDIR=$HOME/tmp

cd $TEMPDIR

array_FileName_category[0]="File1"
array_FileName_category[1]="File2"
array_FileName_category[2]="File3"
array_FileName_category[3]="File4"
a=0
while [ $a -le 9 ]
do
### Creating Source Files
${array_FileName_category[$a]}_file=$TEMPDIR/${array_FileName_category[$a]}_file_$$
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

but this is not working and giving the following errors:

```
File Not found with array prefix.
and the other error is for zero index of array ${array_FileName_Category[$a]} is not working
```

My Desired Output is: If there is FileCategory 'Sports' then at tmp directory using the while loop it will create a file with prefix Sports

Comment: `cd -- "$TMPDIR"; mkdir -p  -- "${array_FileName_category[@]}"`

Comment: @mikeserv mkdir -p will create file or a directory

Comment: Sorry, obviously, directiories. I could swear it said it said directories. Ok. Well, you can use `ksh` directly for the files, I think - is this `ksh93` or ATT `ksh`? `tee` or `touch` would create the files, too, by the way. `touch` would be much safer.

Comment: @mikeserv yes it is ksh93

Comment: Try something like: 'b=$array_FileName_category[$a]; c=${b}_file' and so on

Comment: @RomeoNinov means storing the file category in a separate variable then by the use of other variable create file , if possible please provide an answer using your approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because arrays management in korn shell is far away from other programming languages you can try something like:
Instead of this:

```
while [ $a -le 9 ]
do
${array_FileName_category[$a]}_file=$TEMPDIR/${array_FileName_category[$a]}_file_$$
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

try this:

```
while [ $a -le 9 ]
do
b=$array_FileName_category[$a]
touch $TEMPDIR/${b}_file_$$
a=`expr $b + 1`
done
```

P.S. And IMHO for loop will be better for this purpose

Comment: after modifying your answer in this way if [ ! -d tmp ]
then
    mkdir tmp
fi

TEMPDIR=$HOME/tmp

cd $TEMPDIR
a=0
array_FileName_category[0]="File1"
array_FileName_category[1]="File2"
array_FileName_category[2]="File3"
array_FileName_category[3]="File4"
echo ${array_FileName_category[@]}
while [ $a -le 4 ]
do
b=${array_FileName_category[$a]}
${b}_file=$TEMPDIR/${b}_file_$$
echo ${b}

a=`expr $a + 1`
done it is still not working

Comment: It is giving error File1_file=../tmp/File1_file_33555804:  not found. which means it is not taking as creation of file rather it is taking assignment as a file.

Comment: If you want to create a file see my changes in the script

Comment: this time there is not any error message but on ls -ltr the files are not getting listed , means files count is displaying 8 but there is not any file.

Comment: I miss one line, see above changes

Comment: It is working as my requirement Thanks dude for help :)